# Errors in Flex 3 XML implementation? Rewriting xml:lang

Tags: xml, apache-flex, utf-8, air, interpreter

So I'm working on a quick utility to allow simple editing for TMX files. TMX is basically an XML-based standard for storing multilingual translations. Anyhoo, I'm importing TMX into an Adobe AIR app via a File reference, then grabbing the file stream, slapping the UTF-8 characters into a string, and then that string into an XML object. THus:

```
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(event.target /*file data*/ as File, FileMode.READ);
var fileData:String = stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable);
var tmxXml:XML = new XML(fileData);
```

But, here is the interesting part. If `fileData` is loaded as this:

```
<tuv xml:lang="en">
    <seg>About Us</seg>
</tuv>
```

Flex's XML interprets it as this:

```
<tuv aaa:lang="en" xmlns:aaa="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
    <seg>
        About Us
    </seg>
</tuv>
```

Oh ho interesting! The attribute `xml:lang` becomes `aaa:lang="en" xmlns:aaa="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"`. From my brief research, there is some precedent for this happening, but it's somewhat a sucky assumption. Without creating excessive string replace rules, is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using one of the following?

```
 default xml namespace = xml;
```

or,

```
 use namespace xml;
```

Go through the [Namespaces](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_06.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, can't comment (yet?) so I'll put this here.

I can replicate when adding a non-default namespace to XML with a default namespace:

```
var node:XML = <node xmlns="http://namespacehere.org"/>
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("xml", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace");
node.@ns::base = "myvalue";
```

Output is
`<node aaa:base="myvalue" xmlns="http://namespacehere.org" xmlns:aaa="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>`

Adding `use namespace ns` has no effect and a default namespace is not applicable (it needs to be prefixed).

I have come accross this issue a few times, but have not been able to isolate the cause. Note: one still ends up with an "aaa" prefix no matter what prefix or URI you set in the namespace. Odd.